# React native Text over TouchableOpacity is being cut

Tags: react-native

I am trying to present a letter over touchableOpacity, but when I make the font size of the letter higher - the letter itself is being cut from above, as you can see in the picture down below.

[image: Example of a cutted "s"]

The touchable is:

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}>
     <Text style={styles.letter} > s </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
```

And the styles:

```
export default EStyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'powderblue',
    width: 40,
    height: 50,
    margin: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  letter: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontFamily: 'varela-round',
  },

});
```

When the font size is `lower than 20` it displays fine, `higher than 20` is being cut from above.
  Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@yoel301/stackover

Comment: @yoel it's also cut in your example :)

Comment: remove the margin

Answer (score 0):

Use flexWrap

```
export default EStyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'powderblue',
    flexWrap: 'wrap' // this line
    width: 40,
    height: 50,
    margin: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  letter: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontFamily: 'varela-round',
  },

});
```